# Docker git not found in PATH

Tags: php, laravel, git, docker

I'm still learning docker, and i'm trying to Dockerize a laravel project.

I'm trying to execute laravel composer in docker, however git does not work:

```
[RuntimeException] git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download
```

Git works normal in my local machine.

My Docker file:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer~

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

I've tried to install git using dockerfile:

```
 FROM alpine
 RUN apk add --no-cache git
 CMD ["git","--version"]

 RUN apt-get update && \
     apt-get upgrade -y && \
     apt-get install -y git
```

but docker build dont work:

```
 => ERROR [stage-0 8/8] RUN apt-get update &&      apt-get upgrade -y &&      apt-get install -y git
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache.
    image: php:7.4-apache
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/html
ports:
  - 8001:80
```

How git works in docker? I have to change my environment variables somehow or can i install git on docker?
Or perhaps both and i doing both wrong?

Comment: No need to `RUN curl` to get `composer` and then do `COPY --from`, you can directly do `COPY --from` and it will get `composer` from the docker hub, and you add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git` on your first `Dockerfile` and that will do it.

Comment: Git works the same whether inside a Docker instance, or outside one: it manages a repository full of commits, and can check out a commit to extract the files from it. You will need a version of Git that can run inside the Docker container. That could simply be the Git that is also *outside* the container, provided the appropriate pieces of Git are mounted *inside* the container as well. If they're not, you may need to install Git inside the container (but that's usually not the recommended method).

Comment: Alpine does not use apt as package manager - so `apt-get` will not work.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `COPY --from=composer:2.0 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer` is sufficient to install composer in you docker project .

I created a dockerfile for a laravel project before and this is how it looked

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

# 1. development packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++

# 2. apache configs + document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# 3. mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# 4. start with base php config, then add extensions
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    iconv \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip
#upload
RUN echo "file_uploads = On\n" \
         "memory_limit = 500M\n" \
         "upload_max_filesize = 500M\n" \
         "post_max_size = 500M\n" \
         "max_execution_time = 600\n" \
         > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
# 5. composer
COPY --from=composer:2.0 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed!